# Copy files before resolving dependancies to build an Android application

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an an Android application named 'app' and two jar projects generating 'a.jar' and 'b.jar'. 'app' is gradle project but neither 'a.jar' nor 'b.jar' is non-gradle project.

I want jar files where 'app' depends built automatically when 'gradle build' is executed to build 'app'. I added the place where jar files are created to 'dependencies' closure and tried to insert some tasks to build and copy a.jar and b.jar.

In other words, I want the build tasks done following this order:

1. build 'a.jar' and 'b.jar'
2. 'a.jar' and 'b.jar' are added to the dependancies of 'app'
3. 'app' should be built properly.

I tried to insert tasks building jars by several ways.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    // ... some other dependencies

    compile files('external/a.jar')
    compile files('external/b.jar')
}

android {
  // ...
  // standard android build
  // ...
}

task buildJarA(type: Exec) {
  // the task which builds a.jar and copies into 'external/a.jar'
}

task buildJarB(type: Exec) {
  // the task which builds b.jar and copies into 'external/b.jar'
}

// I tried as follows, but it did not work
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
  preBuild.dependsOn([buildJarA, buildJarB])
}
```

However I could not add the dependencies to compiled the jar files, and dependencies seemed to be resolved at first.
If you know how to run tasks before resolving dependencies, please show me the solution for the problem.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?  I am facing a similar dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `preBuild.dependsOn`, did you try `compileJava.dependsOn`? I've used that to copy files before the main build starts.